# c++11 atomic<int>++ much slower than std::mutex protected int++, why?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, mutex, atomic

To compare the performance difference between `std::atomic<int>`++ and `std::mutex` protected `int`++, I have this test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
#ifndef INT_MAX
const int INT_MAX = numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::max();
const int INT_MIN = numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::min();
#endif
using std::chrono::steady_clock;
const size_t LOOP_COUNT = 12500000;
const size_t THREAD_COUNT = 8;
int intArray[2] = { 0, INT_MAX };
atomic<int> atomicArray[2];
void atomic_tf() {//3.19s
    for (size_t i = 0; i < LOOP_COUNT; ++i) {
        atomicArray[0]++;
        atomicArray[1]--;
    }
}
mutex m;
void mutex_tf() {//0.25s
    m.lock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < LOOP_COUNT; ++i) {
        intArray[0]++;
        intArray[1]--;
    }
    m.unlock();
}
int main() {
    {
        atomicArray[0] = 0;
        atomicArray[1] = INT_MAX;
        thread tp[THREAD_COUNT];
        steady_clock::time_point t1 = steady_clock::now();
        for (size_t t = 0; t < THREAD_COUNT; ++t) {
            tp[t] = thread(atomic_tf);
        }
        for (size_t t = 0; t < THREAD_COUNT; ++t) {
            tp[t].join();
        }
        steady_clock::time_point t2 = steady_clock::now();
        cout << (float)((t2 - t1).count()) / 1000000000 << endl;
    }
    {
        thread tp[THREAD_COUNT];
        steady_clock::time_point t1 = steady_clock::now();
        for (size_t t = 0; t < THREAD_COUNT; ++t) {
            tp[t] = thread(mutex_tf);
        }
        for (size_t t = 0; t < THREAD_COUNT; ++t) {
            tp[t].join();
        }
        steady_clock::time_point t2 = steady_clock::now();
        cout << (float)((t2 - t1).count()) / 1000000000 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I ran this program on windows/linux many times (compiled with clang++14, g++12), basically same result.

1. `atomic_tf` will take 3+ seconds
2. `mutex_tf` will take 0.25+ seconds.

Almost 10 times of performance difference.

My question is, if my test program is valid, then does it indicate that using atomic variable is much more expensive compared with using mutex + normal variables?

How does this performance difference come from?
Thanks!

Comment: In your own words, what exactly are you benchmarking and when do you use that in a real application?

Comment: How does the mutex version even take 0.25 sec? The compiler should be optimizing the loop to single add/sub instructions. Compilers could do the same for the `atomic` variant, but choose not to do that because it would often break intuitive behavior of atomics.

Comment: I measure a factor of about 10000x difference between the two with optimizations enabled (and benchmarking without enabling optimizations is pretty pointless).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your test **does not** really compare the performance of **mutex vs atomic**:

- Your **mutex version** locks the mutex once, then does `12500000` iterations without paying any additional cost for thread synchronization mechanisms.
- In your **atomic version** you pay the cost of the atomic synchronization for every increment, and every decrement of the atomic value (each happens `12500000` times).

In order to compare the two, you need to lock and unlock the mutex for **every increment or decrement** of the value.

**Something like:**

```
void mutex_tf() 
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < LOOP_COUNT; ++i) 
    {
        m.lock();
        intArray[0]++;
        m.unlock(); 

        m.lock();
        intArray[1]--;
        m.unlock(); 
    }
}
```